# PrimeNG autocomplete doesn't show suggestions

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I'm using PrimeNg p-autocomplete in this way:

```
<p-autoComplete id="area" [(ngModel)]="areaSearch" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="retrieveArea($event)" field="name"></p-autoComplete>
```

In component:

```
retrieveArea(event) {
    let searchString = event.query;
    this.results = [];
    searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
    this.service.retrieveAreaCa(searchString).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.result) {
          this.results = response.data.list;
          //list = [{"name": "Paris", "code": "001"}, ...]
        },
        }
      });
  }
```

It worked fine with PrimeNG version 4.0.1 but, after updating to 4.2.0, it doesn't show suggestions on typing. I think there aren't differences to do in code after updating but I can't understand why it doesn't work. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component is not stable yet. 
There are some known issues about it.
I had the same and after update to PrimeNG **4.3.0** everything works fine.

See these [1](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4103) and [2](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4190) from PrimeNG's Github

Comment: Thanks!!! I solved the problem following your first suggestion, adding [immutable]="false" in my p-autocomplete element.